# Is Oregairu Season 3 the end?

Tags: oregairu

I'm wondering if season 3 of *Oregairu* were the end of the light novel because I intend to read the light novel of it if it wasn't the end.

Is season 3 the end of the light novel?

Answer (score 1):

**There is a short sequel released alongside the first BD.**

Wataru Watari, Oregairu's author, [confirmed via a tweet](https://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2020/07/16/my-teen-romantic-comedy-snafu-climax-dvdblu-ray-to-come-with-sequel-novel) that *a six-episode bonus novel titled My Teen Romantic Comedy SNAFU -Shin (New) will be released alongside the first volume of the BD*. The BD's release was on September 25, 2020. Furthermore,

> ...the bonus novel will be a completely new orthodox sequel story to tell "new days."